# there is something like the JDesktoPane of Swing in javaFX?

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

there is something like the JDesktopPane of Swing in javaFX?, Help Please, I am Using Scene Builder and NetBeans!

Answer (score 0):

You should search for javafx MDI.  Plenty of answers here.  They all come down to using JFXPanel in some way, you can add it too a JInternalFrame in a JDesktopPane.  There's no real direct replacement.

I'm doing it now with the netbeans platform instead of JDesktopFrame as there's more functionality already built in.

Sorry, not much of an answer but I can't seem to comment